# How to write a custom template for paginated data in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates, django-rest-framework

With Django Rest Framework, I'm trying to write a custom template for paginated list of snippets. I understand that list function in my view must return paginated response. So I get the page first and send the paginated response. However how can I specify the template name? `get_paginated_response` does not have template_name argument.

Code:

```
def list(self, request):
    page = self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid()
        # fct has no template_name argument!
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: API don't use templates. It is not clear to me why you'd want one. What's the issue you are trying to solve ?

Comment: I want to build a website around my DRF code and for this I have to extend existing templates (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220720/want-to-customize-the-django-rest-framework-browsable-api-page for example). In my list fct, I would like to specify my template name (like they do here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer in the get fct) but I don't see how to specify it in the paginated response.